# How do I solve syntax error in from clause?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, jet

```
string query = "select a.Name,a.Add from GroupDetails a join General b on a.ID=b.Id where b.AccCode='" + label1.text + "'";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
OleDbDataAdapter daName = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{

    txtName.Text = dr["a.Name"].ToString();
    txtAdd.Text = dr["a.Add"].ToString();
}
```

There shows an exception

> Syntax error in FROM clause

Comment: First thing to fix: don't build SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL. Next, I can't see how this is really a C# problem - it looks like you just need to fix your SQL.

Comment: are you sure it says `FROM` ? not `WHERE`? an error in the `WHERE` I could understand... (sql concatenation)

Comment: of course, it is possible that the sql backend doesn't support aliases (the `a` in your example) - what is this connecting to?

Comment: Looks like Access mdb (oledb... ?

Comment: @abhitalks the entire point of oledb is that it can talk to a wide range of ole db providers

Comment: @JonSkeet:: I want to retrieve data from access database. But when I write this code an exception shows.

Answer (score 1):

If it explicitly mentions `from`, then my guess would be that the SQL backend doesn't support aliases (the `a`). However, there are multiple problems:

- the alias
- the sql concatenation
- the unnecessary adapter
- the incorrect columns being read

I would suggest trying:

```
const string query = "select GroupDetails.Name,GroupDetails.Add from GroupDetails join General on GroupDetails.ID=General.Id where General.AccCode=@accCode";

using(var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("accCode", label1.text);
    using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        txtName.Text = (string)dr["Name"];
        txtAdd.Text = (string)dr["Add"];
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth... [*Remarks* The OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that your query is not `SQL Server` because it works OK in SQL Server query window. It could be `Access SQL` or `My SQL`, and you have to specify explicitly `left join`, `right join` or `inner join`. I think you want `inner join` in this case:

```
string query = "SELECT a.Name,a.Add FROM GroupDetails a INNER JOIN General b ON a.ID=b.Id WHERE b.AccCode='" + label1.text + "'";
```

Comment: According to my testing it does *not* work in MSSQL2008: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca3a4/5). Have I overlooked something? :-/

Comment: @cars10 I'm not sure but I tested the original query and it worked without any syntax error, `SQL Server` understands the `JOIN` as `INNER JOIN` while `MY SQL` and `Access SQL` see it as wrong syntax.

Comment: OK, I was more hinged on the `Add` aspect ... - you learn something new every day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Add is the Keyword of SQL, you can [] the field like a.[Add]

```
string query = "select a.Name,a.[Add] from GroupDetails a join General b on a.ID=b.Id where b.AccCode='" + label1.text + "'";
```

Comment: The treatment of the SQL command is of course dependent on the SQL server type. Is it MySQL or MSSQL? In MySql you can actually write `a.Add` but will get an error using `a.[Add]` [MySQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8cb7/3). In MSSQL that is OK.

Comment: Tested it also for [MSQL2008](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca3a4/1): it works woth `a.[Add]` but not with `a.Add`.

Comment: Sorry if mine answer is not correct, cause so far I haven't use mysql before.

Comment: @cars10 the query is not `SQL Server query`, it is `Access SQL`.